# How to customise routes in ScrapyRT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a scrapy project with ScrapyRT integration and I want to customise ScrapyRTs endpoints, so for instance instead of:

```
http://localhost:port/crawl.json?start_requests=true&spider_name=spider&crawl_args={arg:value}
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
http://localhost:port/spider?arg=value
```

Does ScrapyRT have support for something like this natively or do I need to incorporate it with something like FastAPI or Flask?

I tried looking over the [ScrapyRT documentation](https://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I think the thing I was looking for has something to do with the [resources](https://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=resources#resources) but I'm not sure and I don't understand on how to use it.